# Multiple validators for Django 1.11 Model CharField

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

Does anyone know if it is possible to apply multiple validators to a Django 1.11 Model CharField? I am trying to enforce formatting of the field as either: "Use format XX XXXX XXXX" or "Use format XXXX XXX XXX"

```
prefphone = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}$', "Use format XX XXXX XXXX"),RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}$', "Use format XXXX XXX XXX")])
```

The first validation is failing and the second validation is not tested.

If there are alternative methods to achieve my outcome I would be grateful to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my approaching for multiple validator:
Define a custom validator function:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

validator_fn = [
    RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}$', "Use format XX XXXX XXXX"),
    RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}$', "Use format XXXX XXX XXX")
]

def regex_validators(value):
    err = None
    for validator in validator_fn:
        try:
            validator(value)
            # Valid value, return it
            return value
        except ValidationError as exc:
            err = exc
    # Value match nothing, raise error
    raise err
```

Now in field, just use `regex_validators` as a single validator:

```
prefphone = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,validators=[regex_validators,])
```

Comment: Perfect. Works a treat. That is a great solution. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: is it possible to wrap it in a class like the RegexValidator class ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the two validations to be fulfilled

```
def regex_validators(value):

    err = None
    cont = 0

    for validator in validator_fn:
        try:
            validator(value)
            cont+=1
            if cont == 2:
                return value

        except ValidationError as exc:
            err = exc

    raise err
```